# do-while loop does 1 or 2 loops too many

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I have this C function, which to me seems to be behaving randomly in two ways:
1. Only if 'menu' has been typed in, and user_cfg has thus been called, while-loop keeps running a few times after path to an existing file is entered as input, before returning.
2. As the code appears below, I'm getting segmentation fault when path to an existing file is entered as input. As far as I can see, I haven't changed anything in the code since it was working properly 30 minutes ago (except for the problem stated above).

```
char *user_cfg() {
   printf("\nProvide the path for the configuration file or enter \"menu\" to go back:\n");
   char escape[5] = {"menu"};
   char buf[101] = {0};
   char path_input[101] = {0};
   char *userSpecifiedFilepath;

   do {
     if (fgets (buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
       if (sscanf(buf, "%s", &path_input)) {
         userSpecifiedFilepath = path_input;
         if (*path_input == *escape)
           user_cfg();
       }
      } while (!file_exists(userSpecifiedFilepath));
   return userSpecifiedFilepath;
}

bool file_exists(const char *filename) {
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen(filename, "r");
  fclose(file);
  if (file != NULL) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: you know that `if (*path_input == *escape)` dont actually compare the strings, right?

Comment: As far as I've understood, they compare the dereferenced pointers?

Comment: it is comparing the first char of each array, and not the entire array. To compare two string you must use `strcmp()` or `strncmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the address of a local variable. this is an undefined behavior, and probably the reason of the segmentation fault.

A simple (but not the right one :p) way to solve this is declaring your `path_input` as static.

```
static char path_input[101] = {0};
```

Fixing warnings before trying to run your code could help you to avoid those basic issues.

What is the value of `userSpecifiedFilepath` if the `fgets` fail?

Comment: I think this is the answer.  You're trying to return a pointer (userSpecifiedfilepathh) that is allocated within this stack frame.  If you want to make it persistent after the stack frame, you must make userSpecifiedFilepath = malloc(sizeof(sizeOfThePath));

Comment: I'm writing in C though, and as I understand, it's not possible to have static members?

Comment: so by declaring path_input as described above in main(), for example, I should be able to access it in my functions?

Comment: yes, but would be better define this buffer globally, or set a new memory to it with `malloc`, and make the properly `free` later.

Comment: Isn't there any security issues associated with having a global variable in C? I would be able to solve my problems by having a char* that all of my functions can then modify (only one of them will, based on user input). Anything I need to be specifically aware of, before I try to implement that?

Comment: I dont think so, Im not the best person to answer you that, but security breaks is usually related with stack utilization, so a global variable should be safer.

Answer (score 1):

in file exists, the if statement is wrong.  File will become a pointer or NULL '\0', which will not evaluate the way you want it to.  You should make file = to fopen, and then check to see if its NULL. If not, return true.

Comment: Are you sure? Fopen returns true if the file could be opened, thus the if statement evaluates to true, executing the 'fclose' and 'return true' lines?

Comment: it returns a pointer to the File * object, or NULL if it does not exist.

Comment: okay. I applied your suggested changes, however, I'm still having the 2 problems described